# Plotly is blending palette colors in R

Tags: r, graph, plotly, palette

When I'm trying to define a custom palette, say of blue and red colors, I get magenta instead of blue. Let's consider an example taken from **plotly** documentation:

```
library(plotly)
pal <- c("red", "blue", "green")
p <- plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length, 
      color = ~Species, colors = pal)
p
```

This works as expected. Each of three species get it's own color: red, blue or green.

Then I prepare a new data set, removing "virginica", and plotting the result:

```
library(dplyr)
pal <- c("red", "blue", "green")
iris_new<- filter(iris, Species == "setosa" | Species == "versicolor")
p <- plot_ly(data = iris_new, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length, 
      color = ~Species, colors = pal)
p
```

Now "setosa" is red and "versicolor" is blue. We don't use green color, so it seems reasonable to remove it:

```
pal <- c("red", "blue")
iris_new<- filter(iris, Species == "setosa" | Species == "versicolor")
p <- plot_ly(data = iris_new, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length, 
      color = ~Species, colors = pal)
p
```

The result, obviously, should be the same, as in previous chunk of code, but in fact *it isn't*: the blue color is replaced by magenta, and that is very strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is probably just because you have a 2 colour palette mapped to a 3 level factor - until you drop the unused level from the `Species` factor, it's still considered an attribute of the `Species` variable and will affect how it is plotted.

Dropping the factor level makes the colours behave as you expected:

```
iris_new<- filter(iris, Species == "setosa" | Species == "versicolor") %>%
    mutate(Species = droplevels(Species))
p <- plot_ly(data = iris_new, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length, 
             color = ~Species, colors = pal)
p
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! I think, you are right: it is trying to stretch this two colors to the three-level factor.

Comment: Interesting! Would the same thing happen when you only have one factor level?